# why $\overline{f_{q'}} \circ \overline{g_{q}}(q(x))= q'\circ f \circ g(x)$ and $\overline{g_{q}} \circ \overline{f_{q'}}(q(y))= q\circ g \circ f(y)?$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I have some  confusion regarding  Real Projective space  see the [page Number 2](http://www-m5.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/M5/Allgemeines/MA5122_2018W/DT_sol2_2.pdf)

> It is written that

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
    \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\backslash\{0\} @>f>> S^{n} \\
    @VqVV @VVq'V \\
    \mathbb{RP}^{n} @>>\overline{ f_{q'}}> S^{n}/\sim
\end{CD}$$

> Let $g: S^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\backslash\left\{0\right\}$ and
> $f: \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\backslash\left\{0\right\} \longrightarrow S^{n}$ defined by  $f\left(x\right) = \frac{x}{\left\|x\right\|}$ and $\overline{g_{q}}: S^n/\sim \to \mathbb{RP}^n$ .Then

> $\overline{f_{q'}} \circ \overline{g_{q}}(q'(x))= q'\circ f \circ g(x)$

> $\overline{g_{q}} \circ \overline{f_{q'}}(q(y))= q\circ g \circ f(y)$

**My confusion** :Im not getting why  $\overline{f_{q'}} \circ \overline{g_{q}}(q(x))= q'\circ f \circ g(x)$ and $\overline{g_{q}} \circ \overline{f_{q'}}(q(y))= q\circ g \circ f(y)?$

**My thinking** : For $\overline{f_{q'}} \circ \overline{g_{q}}(q'(x))$

we have  $\overline{f_{q'}} \circ \overline{g_{q'}}(q'(x)): S^n \to S^n/\sim \to \mathbb{RP}^{n} \to S^n/\sim \implies  S^n \to S^n/\sim $

After that I'm not able to proceed further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition,

- $\overline{f_{q'}}$ is the map such that $\overline{f_{q'}} \circ q = q' \circ f$; and
- $\overline{g_q}$ is the map such that $\overline{g_q} \circ q' = q \circ g$.

(If this is not clear, read the Lemma 1 again). Thus, $$\overline{f_{q'}} \circ \overline{g_q} \circ q' = \overline{f_{q'}} \circ q \circ g = q' \circ f \circ g, \\ \overline{g_q} \circ \overline{f_{q'}} \circ q = \overline{g_q} \circ q' \circ f = q \circ g \circ f.\, $$